# Galaxy S4 mail group limits

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have a Galaxy S4 that seems to only allow a maximum of 20 contacts in a mail group. Does anyone know how this annoying feature can be changed please?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about an artificial limit of the number of contacts you can add to the default Mail app's "group" section? Because this as far as I know can't be circumvented.

I use Gmail (Gmail app recently stopped working so I switched to their newer "Inbox" app.. thanks google.. >_>) and there's no artificial limit on the number of members of a mail group in Gmail.

Like you have suggested though, it's an annoying "feature", it's unlikely it can be changed in the default "email" app.

[I have a SG4 too]

Edit: I'd recommend trying to **add the people from your contacts to a general contacts group in the "Contacts" app or "People" app** depending on your Android Distribution then choose to email them directly from there. I have one with 52 people I can email using a variety of email clients/apps.